# error C2059: syntax error: 'constant' from struct member declarations

Tags: c++, embedded

This looked like a simple class and structure definition but get a compiler error from Visual Studio C++ when declaring a class instance as a struct member, but can declare global instances of the same class with no problem.
The compile error is on the "Thing" structure member (Thing thing1(1,"1"))

Same compile error if the class member is declared as const and making the parameter to the constructor const

```
class Thing
{
public:
    Thing(int addr, char* str) : theaddr(addr), name(str)      {}
    void info()             { printf("%d %s\n", theaddr, name); }
    int  read()             { /* code to read */                }
    void write(int newval)  { /* code to write newval */        }
private:    
    int  theaddr;
    char *name;
};

Thing global_thing(0,"0");  // WORKS no problem

struct Things
{
    Thing thing1(1,"1");    // ERROR on "Thing" members in struct
    Thing thing2(2,"2");
    .
    .
    .
    Thing thingN(3,"3");

}specificThings;
```

Compiler error "error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'" on the 'Thing' members in struct definition.

The Thing class example above is contrived to demonstrate the problem. What I'm actually trying to do is declare a class to access an SPI device that has register addresses. The system has several devices and some of them have common register names (like "config"). The idea was for the struct to have members that are instances of the class to set the fixed register addresses. Also I want to be able to use the "info()" type function to print the associated register names for debug purposes.

The idea was to do something like this:

```
class DeviceReg
{
    // content like the "Thing" class
};

struct
{
    DeviceReg    config(0x22,"config");
    DeviceReg    status(0x33,"status");
    // and so on...
}rfdev;
```

Then the device access could be like:

```
rfdev.config.write(0x17);
rfdev.config.info();
```

and there could be some other device that could be accessed like:

```
tempsensor.config.write(0x55);
tempsensor.info();
```

So multiple devices could have config or status regs without being forced to name every config register based on the device.

Since what I wanted to do obviously violates C++ syntax, is there another way to accomplish the desired result?

Comment: In which line do you get this error?

Comment: The error is on each of the "Thing" members of the struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default in-class initializers for class members require `{}`-based initializer syntax or `=`-based initializer syntax. There's no `()`-based syntax for  such initializers.

A syntactically proper variant might look as

```
struct Things
{
    Thing thing1{ 1, "1" };
    Thing thing2{ 2, "2" };
    // ...
    Thing thingN{ 3, "3" };

} specificThings;
```

However, this will lead to the next error: you are not allowed to use string literals to initialize `char *` pointers. Use `const char *` maybe?

Comment: this looks like the easiest way to get the result. I've been in the straight 'C' world for a long time and its been a while since using c++ and I wasn't even familiar with the '{}' based syntax. And not sure what '=' meant either - I've got some reading to do!